# NSURL special characters encoding

Tags: xcode, swift

I have this code:

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://****.nl/polen/markers.php/?name=ŁÓDŹ")
```

And when I type this url exactly in the address bar it works it returns a JSON array. But when I try to get the JSON array with Swift it tells me:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

Which means that it didn't find the link. This only happens when I have special characters in the string. Why does this happen and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use something like this:

```
    let str = "http://****.nl/polen/markers.php/?name=ŁÓDŹ"
    let urlString = str.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet())
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString!)!
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly!